# is start-bitstransfer compatible with pester

Tags: powershell, pester

When running start-bitstransfer in a script I'm trying to apply pester to... it doesn't seem to work...
I just tried downloading some random http page (while preparing to do some tropico 5 ;) ... to the pester testdrive, but this doesnt work... 
do .net things not work with pester or such ?

```
set-content "testdrive:\bla.txt" -value  "bla"
Start-BitsTransfer -source "http://www.tropicostrategy.com/p/blog-page.html" -destination 'testdrive:\' -Description "Downloading test"
Get-ChildItem 'TestDrive:\' | out-file c:\temp\b.txt
```

output:

```
Describing get-wallhavens
  [-] downloads a file 591ms
    ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
    ArgumentException: An incorrect value is specified in the Source parameter or in the Destination parameter. Verify that the directory and file names in the Source and Destination parameters are correct.
    at <ScriptBlock>, D:\stack\Projects\Personal\wallchange\download-wallpaper.Tests.ps1: line 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/TestDrive) indicates that you need to use a variable that holds the real location of the temporary storage:

> Working with .NET Objects
>
> When working directly with .NET objects, it's not possible to use the convenient `TestDrive:\` PSDrive. Instead you need to use the `$TestDrive` variable which holds the actual path in a format that .NET understands. For example instead of using `TestDrive:\somefile.txt` use `$TestDrive\somefile.txt` instead.